# Can we move this question to programmers.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, migration

Would it be possible/good idea to move [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928035/how-do-software-projects-go-over-budget-and-under-deliver) to programmers.stackexchange.com ? It's got a 7 delete requests instead of the move option.

Comment: "This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers." - WHO DIDN'T WANT IT!! >:@

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Anna Lear](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/511512#511512) I'm reopening and migrating.

Comment: Will - you could have linked to either the actual question or indeed this question rather than just an image of the question so Anna could see all the discussion.

Comment: @ChrisF the problem is that only 10k users could see the question on SO, so I took a snapshot so she could review the question.  If there is an issue with the answers, they can be deleted.  What gets a question closed/deleted is the *question* itself.  The only other alternative would be to reopen the question on SO and wait for the * to hit the fan while she checked it out, and I didn't know if she'd get my message any time soon.  I'm also expecting to be whisked away to my own meeting hell soon, and so didn't know when *I* would be able to follow up.

Comment: Point taken - but a link to this question where there was some discussion would have been polite.

Comment: @Chris I'll snick over to PSE and add this link to the comments of the question.

Comment: Thank you for saving this beached whale

Comment: How does it work with users that aren't already registered on programmers.stackexchange.com showing answers?

Comment: @ChrisS they get the ghost.  That is, they get the account-does-not-exist treatment.  When they associate their account *I believe* that they'll get wired to their answer automatically.

Answer (score 2):

No.

It's an old question. There's no benefit in moving it. It's been asked, answered and one of the answers has been accepted. There's nothing to be gained **for the question** by having it moved.

It's already closed - just flag it for moderator attention (assuming they don't read this question) for one of them to <strike>delete</strike> lock perhaps.

**UPDATE**

The question has now been migrated - so I'll live with that.

Comment: But why delete (instead of migrate) something that has that kind of interesting input?

Comment: @Pekka - it's been closed for nearly a year - hence my desire for it not to be migrated. Actually I'm not that bothered whether it gets deleted or not - I was just after a way for it **not** to get moved.

Comment: @ChrisF I see. I don't really understand why though, why not migrate if it has a future somewhere else? Or are you speaking as a programmers.SE user and mod saying that programmers doesn't want it? That I could understand.

Comment: @Pekka - I am speaking as a Programmers' user and mod - but I'd argue the same with any **old** question. **I just don't see the value in moving old questions to a new site.**

Comment: @ChrisF fair enough, I'm sure that view comes from a lot of experience. It's just that I have seen some cases recently where something was asked on P.SE that had already been (massively and well) answered on SO proper. That leaves a sort of quasi-duplicate situation that I don't think is optimal. On the other hand, for the specific cases I have in mind, the SO question had not been closed... Or can active SO questions be requested to be migrated to programmers.SE as a policy? I didn't follow the start of that site very closely.

Comment: @Pekka - there is a migration route from SO to Programmers' so new/open questions can be moved by 5 3K+ users.

Comment: Oh, you are here now... no wonder I didn't have any more tag wiki edits to approve ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, even if it gets closed there too, it's still a better place for it :)

Answer (score 1):

In the future, it'd probably be a good idea to refer to [the P.SE FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) when posting these requests... There's a fair bit of resistance to migrated questions in general among some P.SE users, as they do not wish to be seen as a "dumping ground" for aging SO refuse (although I'm afraid there's a bit of NIH involved as well). So don't expect the benefit of the doubt - describe *why* the question belongs on P.SE... and perhaps even why it might *not*. Pay close attention to how it fits within the scope of the site, and whether it follows the 6 subjective guidelines. Example:

#### How do software projects go over budget and under-deliver? - FAQ compliance

- Question is on-topic for Software engineering.
- Does inspire answers attempting to explain why/how.
- Does inspire longer answers.
- Does *not* have a particularly constructive, fair, or impartial tone.
- Does invite sharing experiences.
- Does *not* insist that opinion be backed up with facts/references.
- Is more than just mindless social fun.

**Summary:** Question fits within the scope of the site, meets 4 of the 6 subjective guidelines, and is not wanted on SO.

Comment: I can't find the part of the FAQ that tells me what to do with move requests/migration

Comment: @Chris: normally, you'd just flag for moderator attention (in cases where you couldn't vote to close). In this case, I'd say you did the right thing - it looks to have been a somewhat controversial question, so the extra discussion helps.